# Are any priorities among criteria that are checked during app review?

Tags: ios-appstore

Apple refused for the third time my app. For first two times reason was about semantical, performance issues. Now something wrong with meta info, I forget to set appropriate adult classification.

Does it mean that they haven't found any issue with the binary? Is it an order that they check first binary and then meta?

Answer (score 1):

No, it just depends who's reviewing it. Some reviewers spot the first error and reject the app there and then, whilst others will notify you of all the problems that they find.

For example, my latest rejected iPhone app was rejected mainly for not running correctly when scaled on iPad, but the rejection reason also had some comments from the reviewer regarding the metadata.